# how to assign response json value to typescript variable in angular 4

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am new in angular 4. I am trying get a JSON value using `http.post`.

The response is: `{"status":"SUCCESS"}`

**component**

```js
onSubmit(value: any) {
  console.log("POST");
  let url = `${this.posts_Url}`;
  this.http.post(url, value)
    .subscribe(resBody => {
        this.model.authstatus = resBody.json();
        console.log("Values====="+this.model.authstatus);
    });
}
```

I am getting  `Values====={"status":"Failure"}`

How do I assign the value like `this.model.authstatus = 'Failure'`

Comment: change resBody.json to resBody.json() since its a async call use this console.log("Values====="+this.model.authstatus);statement inside subscribe

Comment: `this` refers to the `subscribe` callback, not `onSubmit`

Answer (score 1):

```
onSubmit(value: any) {
    console.log("POST");
    let url = `${this.posts_Url}`;
    this.http.post(url, value)
      .subscribe(resBody => {
        this.model.authstatus = resBody.json().Status;
        console.log("Values====="+this.model.authstatus);
      });
}
```

This will give output as
      `Values===== 'Faliure'` in console

Answer (score 0):

`this.http.post` is an asynchrounus request which means `this.model.authstatus` will just be empty when you're logging it like this.

You may log your value during the request itself to display proper data.

```
 this.http.post(url, value).subscribe(resBody => {
    this.model.authstatus = resBody.json
    console.log("Values====="+this.model.authstatus);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately as the question has been changed, this answer is now out of date.

Comment: Seems to be true. Yet someone else may find this useful at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Edit : as you aregetting `{"status":"Faliure"}` in the response json then you can use the code below to assign the status to `this.model.authstatus`

```
this.http.post(url, value).
   subscribe((resBody:any) => {
   this.model.authstatus = resBody.json().status;
   console.log(this.model.authstatus);
   }
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately as the question has been changed, this answer is now out of date.

Answer (score 0):

This is an asynchronous call and you want to `console.log` the result before the request has been done.

```
onSubmit(value: any) {
   console.log("POST");
    let url = `${this.posts_Url}`;
    this.http.post(url, value).subscribe(resBody => this.model.authstatus = resBody.json); // This will happen after the request is finished, ~100ms later
    console.log("Values====="+this.model.authstatus); //This will happen right now, when this.model.authstatus is still undefined
  }
```

To fix this, simply move your `console.log` in the http call subscription:

```
this.http.post(url, value).subscribe(resBody => {
    this.model.authstatus = resBody.json();
    console.log(this.model.authstatus
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately as the question has been changed, this answer is now out of date.

Comment: @0mpurdy Yup it has been changed following my answer... Thank you for pointing it :). But whatever I fixed the original issue, no need to tag as answer as long as the problem is resolved I'm okay :D

Comment: I only noticed this after my edit was submitted so I don't think I'll be able to do what is [suggested here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309237/dealing-with-questions-that-are-edited-after-my-answer-has-been-accepted) - just want to make sure this Q&A makes sense for future users

Comment: It seems like a response to this kind of question has been provided on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer

Answer (score 0):

Because you're executing an async call your code does execute it, but goes on. It dosen't wait for the response. So you should do the console.log() in subscribe, since when the response comes, the subscribe inner function is executed.

```
  onSubmit(value: any) {
    console.log("POST");
    let url = `${this.posts_Url}`;
    this.http.post(url, value)
        .subscribe(resBody => {
            this.model.authstatus = resBody.json;
            console.log("Values====="+this.model.authstatus);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
this.http.post(url, value).
   subscribe((resBody:any) => {
   this.model.authstatus = resBody.json();
   console.log(this.model.authstatus);
   return this.model.authstatus :
   }
);
```

Comment: That's not the issue because if it was, he'd have a function logged in console (resBody.json is a function here) and he has undefined.